# Represent a document to a vector by Lucene.

Tags: java, lucene

I want to build document vector for SVM text categorization.
I have indexed my documents to 2 POSITIVE and NEGATIVE documents.
And I selected my features space with IG method.

How can I represent a documents become a vector with tf-idf weight term by Lucene.

Thanks !

Best regard!

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) is a machine learning library in Java. It has utilities to [create document vectors from lucene index](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/creating-vectors-from-text.html) (created from raw text). You can adopt the code as per your requirement.